# Как сделать возможность автоматического выведения типа аргумента-функции? C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, выведение-типов

Есть такой шаблонный метод, который принимает std::function:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename C>
class Deduce
{

    C c = 0;

public:

    template<typename R>
    C then(const std::function<R(C)>& func) {

        return func(c);

    }

};
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при вызове метода не приходилось писать тип возвращаемого значения явно: obj.my_method<my_type>(func)? Я видел код, где этот тип автоматически выводился из типа возвращаемого значения аргумента-функции. Где можно почитать про это?

Comment: как у вас не получается? Здесь : [пример](https://godbolt.org/z/abnaTMoez) компилируется.

Comment: @AlexGlebe плохой пример сделал. Поменял, примел минимальный код, приближенный к задаче. Принимается std::function, а возвращается тип C, а не R. Видимо поэтому. Такой код у меня не компилируется при вызове obj.then(foo)

Comment: @AlexGlebe ссылка битая у вас. Возможно дело в разном способе вызова метода? Я метод вызываю просто как obj.then(func);. При этом компилятор ругается на отсутствие шаблона. Если же указываю явно obj.then<int>(func); То ошибка пропадает и все компилируется

Comment: И передаю туда не лямбду, а обычную функцию

Comment: @AlexGlebe делаю нечто подобное https://godbolt.org/z/9anaPTqjK . Не компилируется, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого достаточно будет использовать автоматическое выведение типа возвращаемого значения функции:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename C>
class Deduce
{
    private: C c{42};

    public: template<typename x_Invocable>
    auto then(x_Invocable && invocable)
    {
        return invocable(c);
    }
};

int increment(int i)
{
    return i + 1;
}

int main()
{
    Deduce<int> deduce{};
    std::cout << deduce.then(increment) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:25,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:25,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:25,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:25,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+C%3E%0Aclass+Deduce%0A%7B%0A%09private:+C+c%7B42%7D%3B%0A%0A%09public:%09template%3Ctypename+x_Invocable%3E%0A%09auto+then(x_Invocable+%26%26+invocable)%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09return+invocable(c)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+increment(int+i)%0A%7B%0A%09return+i+%2B+1%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A%09Deduce%3Cint%3E+deduce%7B%7D%3B%0A%09std::cout+%3C%3C+deduce.then(increment)+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A%09return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.514307650544374,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g111,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Wextra+-Wpedantic+-Winline+-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.1+Executor+(Editor+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:51.48569234945564,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: К сожалению в случае с Std::function это не работает. Ссылка на годболт есть выше в комментариях

Comment: @ComeInRage Это должно работать с std::function без проблем. Не понял, где это - выше? Перед вашим комментарием других нет.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/hezs5K7P7

Comment: @ComeInRage У вас там аргумент неправильно передается - должно быть `then(x_Invocable & invocable)`, иначе будет попытка создать временный объект `std::function` при вызове.

Comment: Ну вот в том и проблема, что мне нужно оборачивать функцию в std::function при передаче в параметр метода. Возможно ли это сделать без явного указания типа метода?

Comment: @ComeInRage Зачем это делать? Вы будете получать бесполезный оверхед на ровном месте.

Comment: а разве можно как-то по-другому сделать метод одновременно принимающим обычные функции и лямбда-выражения?

Comment: Пример из моего ответа может одновременно принимать и обычные функции, и лямбда выражения, и экземпляры `std::function`, и любые другие функторы. https://godbolt.org/z/4e41oPWsY

Comment: действительно. Нужно будет подтянуть эту тему. Однако с шаблонами все еще непонятка. Как в таком случае в вашем примере избежать передачи в функцию не функции (извините за тавтологию), а переменной типа x_Invocable или класса?

Comment: @ComeInRage Никак, но это и не нужно, иначе бы передача лямбд и std::function бы не работала. А если передать туда что-нибудь не вызываемое, типа `int`, то будет ошибка компиляции.

Comment: Т.е. создавая метод таким способом мы перекладываем ответственность за его правильное использование на пользователя, не добавляя никакой защиты "от дурака"? Разве нет никакого способа все таки обезопасить этот метод?

Comment: @ComeInRage ¿О какой безопасности идет речь? Метод не делает ничего опасного.