# Как вывести тип возвращаемого значения из r-value ссылки? С++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, выведение-типов

Изучаю выведение типов в С++ и r-value ссылки. Есть шаблонный метод в классе, который принимает функцию в качестве аргумента:

```
template<typename Return>
Return then(Return&& function) const {
        
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<Return>, "Return cant be called.");
        
    return function();

}
```

И вызов метода:

```
int increment(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}

int main() {

    int a = myclass.then(increment);
    return 0;

}
```

Данный код не компилируется, поскольку нельзя присвоить значение int(*)() переменной a. Я порылся в отладчике и понял, что при передаче функции в качестве r-value ссылки тип Return автоматически становится int(*)() в данном случае, а я хочу, чтобы метод вернул результат функции. Возможно ли вывести тип возвращаемого значения?

Comment: В этом примере нет rvalue ссылок, а не компилируется он из-за кучи других причин, всяких необъявленных идентификаторов, попытки указать Return в качестве типа возвращаемого значения и т.п., а как вывести тип возвращаемого значения уже выяснили в предыдущем вопросе. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1306124

Comment: @user7860670 auto мне не подходит. Однако как же нет rvalue ссылок? Разве Return&& function - это не rvalue ссылка? Тогда что? Честно говоря, я уже совсем запутался. Весь день не могу найти структурированную информацию по этому поводу, одни вопросы

Comment: *"auto мне не подходит"* - ¿почему нет? `Return && function` это не rvalue ссылка.

Comment: @user7860670 Тут вопрос даже не в том, как вывести тип аргумента, а тип возвращаемого значения. Мне нужно, чтобы метод возвращал тот же тип, что и переданная функция

Comment: *"Мне нужно, чтобы метод возвращал тот же тип, что и переданная функция"* - ну так используйте `auto`....

Comment: @user7860670 мне нужен способ без auto. Такое задание)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of

Comment: Только здесь правильно не `auto`, а `decltype(auto)`...

Comment: *"нужен способ без auto"* О таком нужно писать сразу в вопросе. :/ Это единственное ограничение?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat пока что, думаю, да. Честно говоря, я весь интернет перерыл в поисках толковой теории по выводу типов и по шаблонам, но нашел лишь отдельные статьи. Думаю, мне не хватает именно теории, сплошные вопросы)

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо, возможно это будет решением. Однако если && - это не Rvalue Ссылка. Тогда что это? Синтаксис для выведения типа аргумента?

Comment: это универсальная ссылка

Comment: @user7860670 но ведь она построена на r-value ссылках? Или я неправильно понял?

Comment: Нуу, я бы не говорил что она "не rvalue-ссылка". Универсальные ссылки есть подвид rvalue-ссылок (такие rvalue-ссылки, что тип, на который они ссылаются, вы даете выбрать компилятору, как например здесь шаблонный параметр). Здесь `Return` может быть определен или как не-ссылка, или как lvalue-ссылка (в последнем случае `Return &&` сам превратится в lvalue-ссылку).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat благодарю. Однако все равно все не очень понятно, боюсь, что будет еще куча вопросов по этой теме ) Вроде все просто, но сложно

Comment: В комментариях не обяъснить, гуглите "perfect forwarding".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый правильный вариант такой:

```
template <typename F>
decltype(auto) then(F &&function) const
{
    return function();
}
```

Или, еще лучше, с `forward`:

```
template <typename F>
decltype(auto) then(F &&function) const
{
    return std::forward<F>(function)();
}
```

---

Но раз вы не хотите, чтобы компилятор определял за вас тип, то так:

```
template <typename F>
auto then(F &&function) const -> decltype(function())
{
    return function();
}
```

Или, еще лучше, с `forward`:

```
template <typename F>
auto then(F &&function) const -> decltype(std::forward<F>(function)())
{
    return std::forward<F>(function)();
}
```

---

Здесь использован синтаксис trailing return type (замыкающий (т. е. написанный справа) возвращаемый тип). `auto` здесь не определяет тип сам, а просто означает, что настоящий тип написан справа, после `->`.

Обычно `тип функция(...)` эквивалентно `auto функция(...) -> тип`. Но здесь мы вынуждены использовать второй вариант, потому что хотим использовать `function` в `decltype`, а левее списка параметров к нему нельзя обратится.

Есть другой вариант записи:

```
template <typename F>
decltype(std::declval<F>()()) func(F &&function) const
{
    return std::forward<F>(function)();
}
```

Записывая возвращаемый тип слева, мы не можем использовать `function` в `decltype`, но можем использовать `F`.

Comment: Да, спасибо, возможно трайлинг синтаксис мне как раз и поможет. Я знал про него, но даже не сообразил, что его можно использовать) А есть ли какой-либо способ задать вывод типа через шаблоны? Или в случае, если аргумент не передается по универсальной ссылке?

Comment: @ComeInRage *"задать вывод типа через шаблоны"* Не понял. *"если аргумент не передается по универсальной ссылке"* Так она особо ни на что не влияет? Просто убрать `forward`, и возможно немного по-другому вызывать `declval`?